# setInterval inside a for in loop fire immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to make A bunch of calls to Insert a custom events to Google API,
the limit in the API is 10 queries per second, I try adding a setInterval to limit this calls, for some reason it's fire everything at once,
this is my test function:

```
function getGUIDS(){
$.ajax({
    url : 'google_api_url_with_params',
    type : 'get',
    success : function(data){
        for(var i in data.rows){
            rows[i] = data.rows[i];
            setInterval(function(x){
                console.log(data.rows[x][0]);
            },1000,i);
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("Error",data);
    }
});
```

}

anybody? thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Perhaps you meant to write `1000 * i` instead of `1000, i`?

Comment: Also, you're either misusing `for ... in` on an array, or you have an object, in which case `i` doesn't neccessarely have to be a number ?

Comment: It'd be good to see what your `data` looks like.

Comment: The `setInterval` works within the callback function. You need to somehow apply the time interval to the `$.ajax()` call itself.

Comment: hey nicola, no, that's what i ment.

Comment: You're using the third argument to create a closure, and pass `i` into the callback as `x`, but the intervals will still all execute after one second, are you sure you don't want `...}, 1000*i, i);`

Comment: it is an object indeed. my {data} object is an object with arrays inside - something like that ['1002984911.1435312893','0']

Comment: @cars10 what do you mean? how can i apply the time to the ajax call itself? can you write an example please? cheers bro

Comment: In that case `i` will be `1002984911.1435312893`, the key, so you'll need to keep your own counter to create larger values for the interval as the loop procedes. Are you sure you want an interval though, it will keep on going on forever ?

Comment: actually not, it's need to run until the end of the object, i would love to get better ideas if you've got some :)

Comment: What do you mean *"end of object"*? An interval is just that, it's called on regular intervals, in your case every second forever and ever, until you call `clearInterval`, but you have no reference, so you can't clear it, it will just keep on, see this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Lfguf0Lo/**

Comment: yes i know, i didn't took care to it yet but i'll do it when it will work tho..

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a job queue:

```js
var photoidx=0; // sample: pictures from a free JSONP provider ...
var stdJob={url : 'http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=?',
      // format : 'json',  // not really necessary
      dataType:'jsonp',
      success : function(d){
                  $('#out').append('<img src="'+d.items[photoidx++].media.m+'">');},
      error: function(d){console.log("Error");}
    };         // object describing the standard AJAX job in JSONP mode
var jobs=[];   // job queue as a global variable

function getGUIDS(){ // IMPORTANT: $.extend() clones the stdJob
                     // before it is pushed into the job queue.
                     // Without cloning all jobs would have the same data.tags!
    jobs.push($.extend(true,{data:{tags: $('#topic').val()}},stdJob));
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(jobs[jobs.length-1])); 
}
setInterval(function(){if (jobs.length) $.ajax(jobs.pop());},100)

$(function(){
 $('#newjob').click(getGUIDS);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href=# id=newjob>add pic</a> for topic
<input type="text" id="topic" value="Hannover"><br> <!-- my home town -->
<div id="out"></div>
```

`setGUIDS()` will put a request for the API into the job queue. The function inside the `setInterval()` function will then be called every 100 Milliseconds and then process the job through `$.ajax()` accordingly. This will make sure that the API will not be called more than 10 times per second.

I modified your example a little bit to get a working scenario.

In order to do cross-site AJAX call you should use the JSONP protocol instead of POST, since most browsers will block it otherwise.

Comment: thank you vary much mate!! haven't thought that direction with the push&pop thing...cheers!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getGUIDS(){
$.ajax({
url : 'google_api_url_with_params',
type : 'get',
success : function(data){
    for(var i in data.rows){
        rows[i] = data.rows[i];
        setTimeout(function(x){
            console.log(data.rows[x][0]);
        },i * 1000);
    }
},
error: function(data){
    console.log("Error",data);
}
});
}
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the param to setTimeout. It should instead be },i * 1000, i);

Comment: @william.taylor.09 setTimeout is only executed once and so the third parameter is not required.

Comment: @MrCookie, setTimeout is inside of a for loop. In addition, his callback takes in a param (x).